# Routing to the actions with same names but different parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have this set of routes:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "IssueType",
            "issue/{type}",
            new { controller = "Issue", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Here is the controller class:

```
public class IssueController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // todo: redirect to concrete type
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Index(string type)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

why, when i request http://host/issue i get `The current request for action 'Index' on controller type 'IssueController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:`
I expect that first one method should act when there is no parameters, and second one when some parameter specified.

where did i made mistake?

**UPD**: possible duplicate: [Can you overload controller methods in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436866/can-you-overload-controller-methods-in-asp-net-mvc)

**UPD 2**: due to the link above - there is no any legal way to make action overloading, is it?

**UPD 3**: Action methods cannot be overloaded based on parameters (c) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller%28VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would have one Index method that looks for a valid type variable

```
    public class IssueController : Controller  
{  
    public ActionResult Index(string type)  
    {  
        if(string.isNullOrEmpty(type)){
            return View("viewWithOutType");}
        else{
            return View("viewWithType");} 
    }
}
```

EDIT:

How about creating a custom attribute that looks for a specific request value as in this post [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045316/asp-net-mvc-ambiguous-action-methods)

```
[RequireRequestValue("someInt")] 
public ActionResult MyMethod(int someInt) { /* ... */ } 

[RequireRequestValue("someString")] 
public ActionResult MyMethod(string someString) { /* ... */ } 

public class RequireRequestValueAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute { 
    public RequireRequestValueAttribute(string valueName) { 
        ValueName = valueName; 
    } 
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo) { 
        return (controllerContext.HttpContext.Request[ValueName] != null); 
    } 
    public string ValueName { get; private set; } 
}
```

Comment: yep, it's obvious but not actually solution for the issue

Comment: yep, this bring some kind of overloading but too dirty, so i choose to simply rename second method. thanks

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar situation where I wanted my "Index" action to handle the rendering if I had an ID specified or not.  The solution I came upon was to make the ID parameter to the Index method optional.
For example, I originally tried having both:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    //...
}
// AND
public ViewResult Index(int entryId)
{
    //...
}
```

and I just combined them and changed it to:

```
public ViewResult Index(int entryId = 0)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: This could be a solution for .NET 4.0, but I was using 3.5 those days ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using an ActionFilterAttribute that checks the parameters using reflection (I tried it) but it's a bad idea.  *Each distinct action should have its own name.*

Why not just call your two methods "Index" and "Single", say, and live with the limitation on naming?

Unlike methods that are bound at compile time based on matching signatures, a missing route value at the end is treated like a null.

If you want the [hack] ActionFilterAttribute that matches parameters let me know and I'll post a link to it, but like I said, it's a bad idea.

Comment: I already rename second so i have 2 methods. And i get a lot of links to ActionFilterAttribute, indeed - it's a worse solution. thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is mark your second Action with [HttpPost].  For instance:

```
public class IssueController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // todo: redirect to concrete type
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string type)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Who told you that second one is POSTed?

Comment: I've seen this often, especially for Login methods - one Get action to serve the initial view, and Post to accept the login request and redirect. Generally I've seen the `[HttpGet]` tag on the first one as well, not sure which (if any) of the framework versions require that, but tagging both makes it easier to reason about.