# How to call an ActionResult from another ActionResult in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am creating a website for User registeration,display,login etc. I am currently trying to display the details of the user who have signed in. But within the actionResult of login I don't know how will i call the actionResult of display? I am new to asp.net. I need suggestions

```
public ActionResult login()
{
    try
    {
        return View();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

[HttpPost]     
public ActionResult login(DEntities.Users user)
{
    try
    {
        services.CheckUser(user);
        controlsuccess = services.servicesuccess;
        if (controlsuccess == true)
        {

            return RedirectToAction("display");             
            //return View("display");
        }
        else
        { 
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

public ActionResult display()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult display(int id = 0)
{
    try
    {
        DEntities.Users user = services.GetUserbyId(id);
        return View(user);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tag your questions correctly so that it comes in focus of appropriate users and spend some time to format your question

Answer (score 21):

Remove the `[HttpPost]` attribute from the `display` action.

If both actions are in the same controller, then just pass the action name:

```
return RedirectToAction("display", new { id = 1 });
```

Or if the actions are in different controllers, pass the action and controller names:

```
return RedirectToAction("display", "controllername", new { id = 1 });
```

Or if it is necessary to use `[HttpPost]`, you can learn how to
[`RedirectToAction` to a `POST` Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643414/asp-net-mvc-redirecttoaction-with-parameters-to-post-action).