# RedirectToAction with a parameter not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirecttoaction

i am trying to redirect to another action within the same controller
action is called index

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Search(string city)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Rentals", new { CityName = city });

}
```

this is index action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(String CityName)
{


}
```

am i missing something?

Comment: What happens if you change the attribute from HttpPost to HttpGet ?

Comment: if you are looking some kind of hack like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643414/asp-net-mvc-redirecttoaction-with-parameters-to-post-action)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to redirect action which is searching for a matching action but in this case there is no get action, so you have to add a get method to accept redirect. If you want, you can check the HTTPGET or POST inside the method

```
[HttpPost]<---- Remove this 
public ActionResult Index(String CityName)
{


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change `HttpPost` to `HttpGet`

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(String CityName)
{


}
```

Because whenever you call the Action, then the `GET` method will be first called.

Answer (score -1):

As the two actions are in the same controller, you could call the `Index` method directly from  `Search` like this:

```
return Index(city);
```

not necessarily to user the `RedirectToAction` method.