# login user after successful registration without code duplication

Tags: c#, asp.net, optimization, model-view-controller, asp.net-core

I'm using asp.net core with mvc, In my application there is an account controller with register and login actions like as below.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
```

I want to login the user on a successful registration without duplicating the login code in the register action, so in short, How do I redirect the register post to the login post with the LoginViewModel on submitted?

Is it possible to simply call the login action directly from the register action ?

I'm using the same object for the sake of simplicity/compatibility.

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643414/asp-net-mvc-redirecttoaction-with-parameters-to-post-action

Comment: @JayakrishnanGounder that works but i'm still worried that this will result into unknown behaviour or future bugs, but ill add the answer for the lack of a better one

Comment: Instead of calling another post Actionresult, you can separate the code for login and declare it as a method and call that method from registration and login controller.Hope it helps. Otherwise i will post some code snippets

Comment: that will work too, but same concept, ill end up returning another function's task result instead of the action that was called, i still dunno if that will do any conflicts but yeah still a valid helpful option, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the lack of a better answer, ill just post this till someone come up with a better answer from [ASP.NET MVC: RedirectToAction with parameters to POST Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643414/asp-net-mvc-redirecttoaction-with-parameters-to-post-action)

simply call the POST action you wish to redirect to from the method you're in like

```
return Login(loginViewModel).Result; //for async methods
return Login(loginViewModel); //for sync methods
```

disclaimer: i've no idea if that's the absolute right way to do it, or if it is going to introduce any bugs later, but it works for now

Comment: This seems like a weaker solution. Re-POSTing is an extra HTTP round trip, which makes your server do more work and your site seem slower. You should abstract the login code in your existing method to a place that can be called from your existing Login() and Register() functions, and avoid that extra POST.