# How to Overload ActionResult in Asp.Net MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0

I have problem with ActionResult Method overloading in MVC2

I have 3 methods

```
public ActionResult MyMethod()
{  
   var data = ........
   //some unfiltered data from db
   return view(data);
}

public ActionResult MyMethod(string name)
{
   var data = .......
              Where xxx.StartsWith(name)
   //some filtered data by name
   return View(data);
}

public ActionResult MyMethod(int age)
{
   var data = .......
              Where xxx.Equals(age)
   //some filtered data by age
   return View(data);
}
```

How can i overload methods in Asp.Net MVC2?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, you can't overload methods solely by variables.

[Discussion on Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045316/asp-net-mvc-ambiguous-action-methods)

If you must have the same method names, you will need to create an actionfilter attribute and use that as your overload.

Snippet from above discussion:

```
[RequireRequestValue("someInt")]
public ActionResult MyMethod(int someInt) { /* ... */ }

[RequireRequestValue("someString")]
public ActionResult MyMethod(string someString) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: in which namespace is [RequireRequestValue()]

Comment: You have to create the action filter yourself and call it whatever you want.  Re-read the question that I posted to and look @ how he solved his dilemma.

Comment: And can you vrite me filter example if i wana use Mymethod(string a, string b, string c) ?thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far to overload a method with mulitple parameters?  I will help you debug your code, but not write it for you...