# Ambiguous action methods in MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, ambiguous, actionmethod

I'm having some problems with ambiguous action methods in MVC 2.  I've tried implementing the solution found here: [ASP.NET MVC ambiguous action methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045316/asp-net-mvc-ambiguous-action-methods), but that simply gives me a "The resource cannot be found" error as it thinks I'm trying to invoke the action method I ***don't*** want to invoke.  The RequiredRequestValueAttribute class I'm using is the exact same one as what was in the other question's solution:

```
public class RequireRequestValueAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public RequireRequestValueAttribute(string valueName)
    {
        ValueName = valueName;
    }
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        return (controllerContext.HttpContext.Request[ValueName] != null);
    }
    public string ValueName { get; private set; }
}
```

My action methods are:

```
    //
    // GET: /Reviews/ShowReview/ID

    [RequireRequestValue("id")]
    public ActionResult ShowReview(int id)
    {
        var game = _gameRepository.GetGame(id);

        return View(game);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Reviews/ShowReview/Title

    [RequireRequestValue("title")]
    public ActionResult ShowReview(string title)
    {
        var game = _gameRepository.GetGame(title);

        return View(game);
    }
```

Right now, I'm trying to use the `int id` version, and instead it's invoking the `string title` version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution assumes that you must absolutely use the same URL regardless of if you're selecting by ID or name, and that your route is set up to pass a value to this method from the URL.

```
[RequireRequestValue("gameIdentifier")]
public ActionResult ShowReview(string gameIdentifier)
{
    int gameId;
    Game game = null;
    var isInteger = Int32.TryParse(gameIdentifier, out gameId);

    if(isInteger)
    {
      game = _gameRepository.GetGame(gameId);
    }
    else
    {
      game = _gameRepository.GetGame(gameIdentifier);
    }

    return View(game);
}
```

**Update:**  According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller%28VS.100%29.aspx): "Action methods cannot be overloaded based on parameters. Action methods can be overloaded when they are disambiguated with attributes such as NonActionAttribute or AcceptVerbsAttribute."

Comment: Hmm... interesting option.  I may resort to it if I can't find something cleaner.

Comment: I'm not aware of a clean way for the routing engine to choose one of two action methods based on a parameter being castable to a certain type.  Maybe someone will prove me wrong.

Comment: Yeah, further research shows you're right.  Thanks for the help!