# ASP.net MVC Can you overload an Index() HttpPost?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, forms

Let's say I have a page with 2 forms that both submit different data on the same page, one submits two ID's, and the other submits only 1 ID. They are both posting back to the same page (itself). Here is what the HTML would look like...

```
<form method="post">

<select name="regID">
...
</select>

<select name="jobID">
...
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Add">

</form>

<form method="post">

<button name="ID" type="submit" value="@ID">Remove</button>    

</form>
```

Now, to handle the first form in the controller I can do

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(int regID, int jobID)
 {
 ....
 }
```

However, if I try to handle the second form by adding

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(int ID)
 {
 ....
 }
```

When I click the submit button, I will now get the error

```
The current request for action 'Index' on controller type 'UserJobController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32) on type careerninja.Controllers.UserJobController
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32, Int32) on type careerninja.Controllers.UserJobController
```

So, is it possible in the controller to overload the [HttpPost] method with different values to handle 2 different sets of form data, or is this not possible? Is there another solution I might not be grasping to handle this sort of issue?

Basically, for the second form I want to have a "Remove" button that when clicked, calls the controller to remove the item, removes the item, then returns the Index() view.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you overload controller methods in ASP.Net MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436866/can-you-overload-controller-methods-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045316/asp-net-mvc-ambiguous-action-methods

Comment: No. But you can create a "Remove" action method and be done with the error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think an improvement in your design would make the problem you are having not an issue anymore.  It sounds like you believe everything might have to go through your `Index()` method, which is not the case.  Redesigning your method's name to the behavior of what the action is doing is typically how I name my methods.

> Basically, for the second form I want to have a "Remove" button that when clicked, calls the controller to remove the item, removes the item, then returns the Index() view.

So create your method called `Remove()` and have it redirect to the `Index()`

```
public ActionResult Remove(int id)
{
  // do some work 

  this.RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I would recommend making your method names represent what they are doing.

```
public ActionResult Add(int regID, int jobID)
{
  // do some work

  this.RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

*Note*: This is also an important design for the User Interface.  When a page typically does a POST to the server, and then the server returns HTML, if the users decides to refresh the page , a popup will typically be presented asking them if they want to resubmit data.  Instead the previous examples did a server side redirect, which starts a second request as a GET and prevents the popup from occurring on refresh.