# ambiguous between two controller methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Inside my asp.net mvc4 controller I have two action methods

```
public ActionResult Projects()
```

and

```
public ActionResult Projects(string s)
```

on debugging when I'm send string to this second method I'm getting error that current request is ambiguous between this two methods.

Why is that, since those have different method signature?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC ambiguous action methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045316/asp-net-mvc-ambiguous-action-methods)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MVC it cannot support two actions with the same name... even with differents signatures.
The only exception is when one of the actions is decorated with a different verb attribute, like `[HttpPost]`.

If HttpPost is not suitable for you... you need to change the action name.

Just checking around, there are some alternatives to help you having 2 actions with the same name: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1045616/7720

Comment: I usually solve this through routing.  You can use standard routing to fix it by moving them to different controllers, or you can use stuff from attributerouting.net.  You can always give them different names of course

Comment: I'm not a big fan of Routing... but you are right. In my project, we have 60 controllers always using the standard route.

Answer (score 4):

Decorate them with verbs, They have different function signature but **most important they have same ActionName**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Projects()


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Projects(string s)
```

Or Change the action name of one of these mehod

Answer (score 1):

String is `nullable type`.

So your route will match both methods for `optional`.

In your case below are valid

> /Home/Projects/
>
> /Home/Projects/Business/

So decorate with different name

```
 public ActionResult ProjectBySting(string s)
```

or verb like `[HttpPost]/[HttpGet]`