# The current request for action 'BildirimGoruntule' on controller type 'BildirimController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:

Tags: asp.net-mvc

At runtime page meets me with error: there is an ambigous but they seem different by parameter.. Why this happen? 
it happens When I click the row in table. Here is the route part : ...

```
    table += "<tr>" +
"<td style='text-align:center;width:40%'><a href='/Bildirim/BildirimGoruntule?bildirimid="+Data.bildirimid+"'>" + Data.date + "</a></td>" +
"<td style='text-align:center'>" + Data.version + "</td>" +...

  public ActionResult BildirimGoruntule()
        {
            ...
        }

    public ActionResult BildirimGoruntule(int bildirimid)
    {
      ...
    }
```

Comment: Does the *compiler* say it's ambiguous, or does this happen at *runtime* for a specific request?  "The current request" suggests the latter.  If it's the latter, what is the request and how are the routes defined?

Comment: yeah you right this happens at runtime. sory I edit it

Comment: You can't have 2 actions with the same name even if they have different parameters, unless they handle different http verbs (like one handling GETs and the other POSTs)

Comment: However you can create your custom `ActionMtehodSelector` attributes that look at the parameters. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045316/asp-net-mvc-ambiguous-action-methods)

Comment: @DanielJ.G. I understood but Which do u advice me in my situation ?
I think I should add [HttpPost] for second(with parameter) method ?

Comment: If the second action is really meant for a POST request, then add the [HttpPost] attribute. Otherwise if you really want separated actions take a look at the link in my comment above.

Comment: @DanielJ.G. Okey I see then I should use my own class to handle this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just add [HttpGet] for the first method, if it is a get and [HttpPost] verb for the second method, as it seems a post action. If both are get methods you need to either change your action method name or use [ActionName()] attribute to give different name for one the action methods.