# Dotnet core can't distinguish actions with the same name but different parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

The following code

```
public class OrderController : Controller
{   
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

It can work well on ASP.NET 4.5,but it doesn't work on dotnet core 1.1 .The Error Messsage:

> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionSelector[1]
>   Request matched multiple actions resulting in ambiguity. Matching actions: WebAPI.Controllers.OrderController.Get (WebAPI)
>   WebAPI.Controllers.OrderController.Get (WebAPI)
>
> fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
>   Connection id "0HL3F88N44HR6": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:
>   WebAPI.Controllers.OrderController.Get (WebAPI)
>   WebAPI.Controllers.OrderController.Get (WebAPI)

Answer (score 2):

It is not a problem of Asp.Net.Core, exact the same behaviour is in both MVC4 and MVC5.

ASP.NET MVC does not support method overloading, there is a lot of SO questions and articles about this:

- [Can you overload controller methods in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436866/can-you-overload-controller-methods-in-asp-net-mvc)
- [ASP.NET MVC ambiguous action methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045316/asp-net-mvc-ambiguous-action-methods)
- [Can we overload MVC controller action methods? (MVC Polymorphism)](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/846403/can-we-overload-mvc-controller-action-methods-mvc)
- and so on

There could be a set of solutions to get the desired behaviour, one of commons are:

First - to use built-in attribute, derived from `ActionFilterAttribute` or `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute` in MVC4 (it is the base class for retrieving the required action while processing your request). For example `ActionNameAttribute`, `HttpGetAttribute`, `HttpPostAttribute`, etc:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}

[ActionName("GetById")
public string Get(int id)
{
    return "value";
}
```

Or simply rename your method.

Another solution is to create your own attribute, derived from `ActionFilterAttribute` as suggested at second link.

When I faced this problem, I solved this by passing a nullable parameter in the following manner:

```
public object Get(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };

    var passedId = (int) id;
    return GetValueByPassedId(passedId);
}
```

Comment: It can not work fine in ASP.NET 4.5, check related links, here described the same problem in different versions of ASP.NET

Comment: It's the demo code which the Visual Studio generate. Orz

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by adding HttpGet attribute, like this.

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
// GET api/values/5
public string Get(int id)
{
    return "value";
}
```

It is because in ASP.NET 5, for web API routing, Routes.MapHttpRoute method was used and for ASP.NET MVC Routes.MapRoute method. In ASP.NET Core, Routes.MapRoute method is used.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
// GET api/values/5
[HttpGet("Get/{id}"]
public string Get(int id)
{
    return "value";
}
```