# AmbiguousMatchException in ActionMethodSelectorAttribute when two or more requests are submitted at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have multiple actions methods in a Controller that share the same ActionName, like this:

```
[ActionName("Example")]
[DefinedParameter(Name = "xID")]
[HttpPost()]
public ActionResult ExampleX(Guid xID)
{
    ....
}

[ActionName("Example")]
[DefinedParameter(Name = "yID")]
[HttpPost()]
public ActionResult ExampleY(Guid yID)
{
    ....
}
```

In addition to this I use a action selector via the DefinedParameter attribute, like this:

```
public class DefinedParameterAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        HttpRequestBase request = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
        return request[this.Name] != null;
    }
}
```

In most cases this works perfectly.

In some cases however I get the following error:

"AmbiguousMatchException 
    Exception message: The current request for action 'Example' on controller type 'ExampleController' is ambiguous between the following action methods: ...."

I get this error when:

1. I submit a request (that takes some time) with example parameter xID.
2. While the request from step 1 is still processing on the server (no response returned yet), I submit a second request (example parameter yID).

I discovered that in those cases the request indeed contains both parameters; in my example xID and yID. That explains the error.

So it seems that the server somehow reuses the same request and adds the parameter from the second submit.

NB: Please know that I mostly use action methods with a unique name. That's the best way to go. But in some cases the described example can be a better approach.

How can I solve and/or avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

MVC doesn't support method overloading based solely on signature, so this will fail:

Same question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045316/asp-net-mvc-ambiguous-action-methods)

Check this [blog](https://www.ryadel.com/en/asp-net-mvc-fix-ambiguous-action-methods-errors-multiple-action-methods-action-name-c-sharp-core/) for same example

Comment: That solution is the same as I'm using. As I said, it mostly works, only not in some edge cases.