# ASP.NET Core Web API : routing confusion

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am learning how ASP.NET Core Web API works, and I am a bit confused on how request's are routed within a controller.

I understand that the URI is typically `/controllername-"controller"/action`. So something like `UsersController` would be `/api/Users/`.

However I have seen some variations in code at work, that either don't include a `Route` attribute, and the attribute doesn't include a placeholder identifier.

For example a method called `Get(int id)` within a `UsersController` is said to be `users<id>` but how does .Net know this?

Furthermore for something that isn't an obvious `Get` or `Put`, but an actual method name like `GetWidgetInfo(int widgetId)`. I'm assuming .NET Core is able to just figure out this takes a URI resource parameter appended after the function name? IE: `api/users/getwidgetinfo/<id>`. What are the rules for this?

(New .NET Core seems to always have placeholder values on the attribute, but I'm still not sure how it handles naming/routes with methods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you clarify if your controller is inheriting `ControllerBase`? I am assuming you are.

For your first question, since adding a "users/..." to every endpoint is the users controller would be redundant, it is common to have a `[Route("api/[controller]")]` (or variations of it) before your controller class declaration. My understanding is that since your controller class inherits the `ControllerBase` class, .NET implicitly knows to route all requests to /users to the controller whose name is "users" (unsure about case sensitivity).

For your second question, this MS docs sheet https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0
, and this StackOverflow post may give you some more insight [ASP.NET MVC ambiguous action methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045316/asp-net-mvc-ambiguous-action-methods).

For exact inner workings, this MS documentation may contain the information you need
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/porting-existing-aspnet-apps/routing-differences

Comment: It's actually inheriting `ApiController`, (Which I think is older .net?)

Comment: Perhaps the results are same regardless